# How to compare values in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Filename||status
---------------
A|10
A|22
B|10
```

My expected output is

```
B|10
```

I should not get output whose file name is both 10 and 22 status

Comment: Please clarify your problem and add the query you used so far for getting your output

Comment: My current Query is select * from table where status= 10;

Comment: Am getting 2 rows A || 10 and B || 10 but I should not get file names whose status is 10 and 22

Comment: @CarloCe My current Query is select * from table where status= 10; Am getting 2 rows A || 10 and B || 10 but I should not get file names whose status is 10 and 22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to restate your question - you're looking for the files that have a status of 10, but do not have a status of 22. Once the question is phrased like this, we can easily translate the requirement to SQL using the `exists` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable a
WHERE  status = 10 AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   mytable b
                   WHERE  a.filename = b.filename AND
                          b.status = 22)
```

Comment: The OP stated `I should not get output whose file name is both 10 and 22 status` this only checks if it has status `10` and not status `22` but doesn't check for the reverse.

Comment: Hi Mureinik. . Thanks for ur suggestions. Ur query worked . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query that obtain the result:

```
WITH files AS(
    SELECT 'A' AS filename, 10 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' AS filename, 22 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' AS filename, 10 AS status FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C' AS filename, 22 AS status FROM dual 
)
    SELECT filename, status
    FROM files
    WHERE filename NOT IN (
        SELECT f1.filename
        FROM files f1, files f2
        WHERE f1.filename = f2.filename
          AND f1.status = 22
          AND f2.status = 10
    );
```

I added a C record in the table to check for result correctness:

```
B   10                                    
C   22
```

Comment: The OP stated `I should not get output whose file name is both 10 and 22 status` this only checks if it has status `10` and not status `22` but doesn't check for the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

> I should not get output whose file name is both 10 and 22 status

In other words, you can have status `10` and no rows with status `22` or you can have status `22` and no rows with status `10`.

Neither of these queries requires a self-join (they both only use a single table scan):

**Query**:

```
SELECT filename
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY filename
HAVING (   COUNT( CASE status WHEN 10 THEN 1 END ) > 0
       AND COUNT( CASE status WHEN 22 THEN 1 END ) = 0 )
OR     (   COUNT( CASE status WHEN 10 THEN 1 END ) = 0
       AND COUNT( CASE status WHEN 22 THEN 1 END ) > 0 );
```

**Output**:

```
FILENAME
--------
B
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT filename,
       status
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( CASE status WHEN 10 THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY filename ) AS s10,
         COUNT( CASE status WHEN 22 THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY filename ) AS s22
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  status IN ( 10, 22 )
)
WHERE  ( s10 > 0 AND s22 = 0 )
OR     ( s10 = 0 AND s22 > 0 );
```

**Output**:

```
FILENAME STATUS
-------- ------
B            10
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  select Filename, min(status)
    from [table_name]
  group by Filename
having count(*) = 1
```